# Optimally searching a substring within a string java

Tags: java, android, search, optimization, substring

I have a list of phone numbers which may or may not have country code included in them. I get a number from a backend service which always contains country code. So I have optimally found the number which matches with the number came from backend service.

Right now what I am doing is :

```
for(String number : backendNumbers){
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : contactMap.entrySet()){
        if(number.endsWith(entry.getKey()) && entry.getKey().length() > MINIMUM_CONTACT_LENGTH){
            Log.i(TAG, "Found name for "+entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getKey()+":"+entry.getValue());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Where contact map is a map of contacts like this =<"01710111111", "Some name"> -> This key may or may not contain the country code. In most cases, they don't.

When I get a number from Backend which always contains country code like this: "+8801710111111".

Now the problem with this approach is there is an overhead of generating the contact map each time I need that map. Also in the case where I get N numbers from the backend for each number I need to loop around the whole contact map just to find a name.

So what I could do better here? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for the given loop code you can shift to the `map.keySet()` to only deal with strings keys.
otherwise this approach is not wrong, this is the minimal overhead you will need when you are comparing values of hashmap especially.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the problem with this approach is there is a overhead of generating the contact map each time I need that map.

Well, either you have some structure to facilitate the search or you search through the whole list.

I'd create a `Map<String, String>` of number to name. When creating the map also calculate the minimal length of the number `minLength`.

Then, given a backend number, lookup not just the number but also all suffixes up to the length of `minLength`.

```
for (int beginIndex = 0; beginIndex <= (backendNumber.length() - minLength); beginIndex++) {
    String name = nameByNumber.get(backendNumber.substring(beginIndex));
    if (name != null) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This will give you something like O(max length of backend number - min length of number) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both collections are big, the following could gain a factor of 10:

```
for (char c='0'; c<='9'; ++c) {
    Map<String, String> submap = new Map<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : contactMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        if (key.length() > MINIMUM_CONTACT_LENGTH
              && key.charAt(key.length() - 1) == c) {
          submap.put(key, entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    for(String number : backendNumbers){
        if (!number.isEmpty()
                 && number.charAt(number.length() - 1) == c) {
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : submap.entrySet()) {
                 .... do what you did
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is trivial: One string can only be a substring of another one, if both end with the same character. So I splitt both collections accordingly and saved me tests like xxxxx1 against xxxxx2.

Obviously, you can use two last digits instead, but this adds more overhead. The original complexity is `O(m*n)`, with this trick it's `O((m+n)*k + (m/k)*(n/k))` where `k` is the number of buckets. I'm assuming the last digit(s) to be uniformly distributed, which they usually are.

It could be done much better....

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Map of the backendnumbers with and without the country code(isn't it always 3 chars?)

```
Map<String,String> backendMap = new HashMap<>();
for(String number : backendNumbers){
    backendMap.put(number,number);
    backendMap.put(number.substring(3),number);
}
```

then you could make simply a get on the backendMap to find (or find not) the number(assuming the number has the country code always in the same form).

Comment: No sadly the country code isn't always 3 chars.it can be 1,2,3 or 4 char.